# R programming: how to "plot" a data file that's a "column", not a row?

Tags: r, plot, row

I'm new to R, and I have a data file in txt format like this:

```
17.72
15.29
15.18
15.58
16.52
28.77
26.08
23.69
14.76
13.90
14.37
18.02
20.67
23.72
13.66
```

I wish to read it into R and draw a line with all data points having a 'o' as dot so I:

```
y<-read.table('~/my.data')
length(y)
```

It prints "1". I wish that y is an array of 31 elements as I have in the file. How can I make it, and then plot in a graph, with x-axis having 1-31?

Thanks!

Comment: `read.table` creates a dataframe object so `length` is not used for this type of object but you have to use `dim`. If you want a vector, just do `as.vector(df)` and then you can use `length`

Comment: Try `y <- t(read.table('~/my.data'))`. `t()` transposes a matrix or dataframe, which should give you the output you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `y<-read.table('~/my.data')`, `R` reads your data as a `data.frame`. Since it does not have a `header`, the column name is assigned as `V1`.

Below will tell you number of items:

```
length(y$V1)
```

Finally you can plot it with:

```
plot(y$V1)
```